# css grid a 2² grid with two titles and two lists

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I want to have a 2x2 grid with two h3 on top and two ul in the bottom

```css
#listgallery {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "title" "list";
}

h3 {
  grid-area: title;
}

ul {
  grid-area: list;
}
```

```html
<div id="listgallery">
<h3>title1</h3>
<ul>
  <li>list1</li>
</ul>
<h3>title2</h3>
<ul>
  <li>list2</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

that displays all header over eachother same as lists

```
#listgallery {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
            grid-template-areas:
            "title title"
            "list list"
            ;
            h3 {
                grid-area:title;
            }
            ul {
                grid-area:list;
            }
        }
```

same as above

```
#listgallery {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
        }
```

this displays headers on the left lists on the right
I could use that and adjust my html like this:

```
<h3>title</h3>
<h3>title</h3>
<ul><li>list</li></ul>
<ul><li>list</li></ul>
```

but that feels just wrong. So is there any css solution to solve that?

---

```css
#listgallery {
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}
#listgallery h3 {
 grid-row: 1;
}
#listgallery h3:nth-child(7), #listgallery h3:nth-child(5) {
 grid-row: 3;
}
```

```html
<div id="listgallery">
<h3>title1</h3>
<ul>
  <li>list1</li>
</ul>
<h3>title2</h3>
<ul>
  <li>list2</li>
</ul>
<h3>title3</h3>
<ul>
  <li>list3</li>
</ul>
<h3>title4</h3>
<ul>
  <li>list4</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

that works for some reason but the css still isn't pretty

Comment: hint use `bootstrap4 grid`

Comment: and it woulb be 2*2

Comment: if you dont want to use bootstrap grid use flexbox but i ll recommend b4 grid!!! :-)

Comment: ` grid-area:title;`will put elements in the first area named this way and eventually make them spanning through all areas of the same name.

Comment: Note. I do not recommend using bootstrap4 for this one thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For that little of elements, you can make your code simplier and may use only what is needed .

```css
#listgallery {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr; 
}

h3 {
  grid-row: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="listgallery">
  <h3>title</h3>
  <ul>
    <li>list</li>
  </ul>
  <h3>title</h3>
  <ul>
    <li>list</li>
  </ul>
  </div>
```

---

**<del>to be clarified from comment:</del>**

```css
#listgallery {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr; 
}

h3 {
  grid-row: 1;
}
h3 ~h3 ~h3 {
grid-row: 3
}
```

```html
<div id="listgallery">
  <h3>title</h3>
  <ul>
    <li>list</li>
  </ul>
  <h3>title</h3>
  <ul>
    <li>list</li>
  </ul>
  <h3>title</h3>
  <ul>
    <li>list</li>
  </ul>
  <h3>title</h3>
  <ul>
    <li>list</li>
  </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: Upvoting your answer because it is more elegant than mine. I swapped out my code for yours because my answer is more thorough, but cited you as this is the correct code solution.

Comment: ok, thx, but what If I told u that I simplyfied my problem and I actually want a 2x4 grid so two pairs of title and list next to each other?

Comment: @Hisfantor then again, tell h3 on which row to stand nth-child can do the job . Show us what you have in this configuration ;)  i added a second snippet to show a possible option

Comment: I added an other solution to my question, but both yours and mine look more hacked than pretty css, thx anyway

Answer (score 2):

> that feels just wrong

It's not. CSS grid expects an html layout of items within each row, left-to-right, and the rows stacked top-to-bottom:

```css
#listgallery {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}
```

```html
<div id="listgallery">
  <h3>title</h3>
  <h3>title</h3>
  <ul>
    <li>list</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>list</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

You can set it up with the HTML structure you want, but the CSS is slightly more complex:

*Edit Note: G-Cyr has a much more elegant solution than mine for achieving this effect:*

```css
#listgallery {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:"h31 h32" "ul1 ul2"
}

#listgallery h3:first-of-type{
  grid-area: h31
}

#listgallery h3:last-of-type{
  grid-area: h32
}

#listgallery ul:first-of-type{
  grid-area: ul1
}

#listgallery ul:last-of-type{
  grid-area: ul2
}
```

```html
<div id="listgallery">
  <h3>title</h3>
  <ul>
    <li>list</li>
  </ul>
  <h3>title</h3>
  <ul>
    <li>list</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. Recommending Bootstrap for this is common for less-skilled developers.

Comment: no need to add the code of another answer. Having multiple answer is the purpose of this. Anyone can see the solution of G-Cyr

Comment: @TemaniAfif you're right, I don't want to take credit for his answer. Changed mine back.

Answer (score 1):

You can also consider a column direction for this:

```css
#listgallery {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}
```

```html
<div id="listgallery">
  <h3>title 1</h3>
  <ul>
    <li>list</li>
    <li>list</li>
    <li>list</li>
    <li>list</li>
  </ul>
  <h3>title 2</h3>
  <ul>
    <li>list</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

This will do:

```
<div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">
                    <h3>title</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6">
                    <h3>title</h3>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">
                    <ul>
                        <li>list</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6">
                    <ul>
                        <li>list</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

            </div>
```